# Ordinal arithmetic $(2\cdot (\omega+1))\cdot \omega$ and $\gamma = \bigcup \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}\}$ Cantor Normalform

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Ordinal arithmetic $(2\cdot (\omega+1))\cdot \omega$ and $\gamma = \bigcup \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...\}$ Cantor Normalform

I understood that $(2\cdot (\omega+1))\cdot \omega=(\omega+1)\cdot \omega = \omega\cdot \omega$ for the first one. Is this correct?

I know that the epsilon nought is $\varepsilon _{0}=\omega ^{\omega ^{\omega ^{\cdot ^{\cdot ^{\cdot }}}}}=\sup\{\omega ,\omega ^{\omega },\omega ^{\omega ^{\omega }},\omega ^{\omega ^{\omega ^{\omega }}},\dots \}$, so $\gamma$ should equal $\varepsilon _{0}$.

Is the attempt correct like this? If so, is $\varepsilon _{0}$ in Cantor Normalform? How to proceed?

Comment: Ordinal $+$ and $\times$ are associative...For ordinals $x,y$, picture $xy$ as $y$ consecutive copies of $x.$... If $\gamma$ is any set of ordinals then $ \sup \gamma=\cup\gamma.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\cdot(\omega+1)=2\cdot\omega+2=\omega+2$, not $\omega+1$, but $(\omega+2)\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot\omega$, so you ended up in the right place. The Cantor normal form of $\epsilon_0$ is $\omega^{\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: I have a question about this. Addition is not commutative in ordinal arithmetic. ω+2≠2+ω. The second one is indeed equal to ω because of the way the sum is defined in the ordinals. The first one is the successor of the successor of ω which is strictly bigger than ω. What is wrong in what I wrote?

Comment: @Mariacosta: There is nothing wrong with what you wrote in this comment.

Comment: Then I don't understand how $(ω+2)⋅ω=ω⋅ω$ . Could you explain this to me?

Comment: @Mariacosta: $$(\omega+2)+\omega+2)=\omega+\omega+2)=\omega\cdot2+2\,;$$ $$(\omega\cdot2+2)+(\omega+2)=\omega\cdot3+2\,;$$ and in general $$(\omega\cdot n+2)+(\omega+2)=\omega\cdot(n+1)+2\,.$$ The limit of these ordinals is $\omega\cdot\omega$.